# Which formats does Apple Newsstand accept?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios, newsstand

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Newsstand content can be published in PDF format.  Via a Newsstand iOS app of course.

What other formats does a Newsstand app work with?  Is epub ok?

Does Apple provide any information on content formats (I haven't found any)?

Comment: You're creating an App which will be published in NewsStand (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ConfiguringStoreTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH2-SW7)

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Newsstand is just a special "Store" where you can download a 'magazine' app and the Newsstand itself which tracks the "issues" that your magazines have available

So your Newsstand app can display anything it wants in any format it can decode and display - an issue is just a big bundle of data and the magazine app is just an app that decodes and displays that data.

Apple don't give you any information about content formats as they don't care and don't specify.

PDF **is** a popular format as you can easily display PDFs on iOS using WebKit, indeed most magazines seem to use Webkit for displaying their data since it allows you to show a bunch of formats and it works well with embedded links.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any links to this style of using WebKit?  It sounds like a mini website will do fine for each issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any real tips for programming with WebKit. Start with Apple's developer resources and examples.